# Unable to drop a Filedrop in Wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a window in WPF and in there is a wrappanel there will be displayed some objects. 
I want to drag a file from windows explorer into my wrappanel. 
I have Drop, DragOver and DragEnter events on my wrappanel.
But no event is firing when I drag over the wrappanel or drop a "FileDrop" on the wrappanel. 
I have already tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144799.aspx) example.

What's wrong with this wrappanel?

btw.: I already set "AllowDrop" to true.

Comment: Does your `WrapPanel` have some background colour (even if only transparent)? Without that it won't be hit test visible

Comment: It's set to white. When I add a MouseMove event to it. This event is firing but the other events aren't.